# Screen wide container with fixed size sizebar divs and responsive center div?

Tags: css

I am creating a blog template where the content (for desktop viewers) is almost centered.

I would like to build a container div that fills the screen area without creating excess scroll. Within that div container, I'd like one fixed div on the left (e.g. 250px) and one fixed to the right (e.g. 350px) with the center div being responsive until it reaches a max width of 1000px.

Can this be done with a function like calc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed possible with **[`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)**, by setting `width: calc(100% - [combined widths])`.
In your specific example, it would be `width: calc(100% - 250px - 350px)`.
Note that **[`max-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width)** will still come into play, to prevent the central `<div>` from exceeding `1000px`.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  height: 100vh;
  float: left;
}

.left {
  background: red;
  width: 250px;
}

.right {
  background: green;
  width: 350px;
}

.center {
  background: blue;
  width: calc(100% - 250px - 350px);
  max-width: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="center"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Didn't realize I had to set the fixed widths individually within the equation.

Comment: ^ Glad it helped :) You can always get a little technical and make use of CSS variables. That way you only have to set one value to have it applied to both the `width` of the fixed column and the `calc()` of the variable column. Having said that, it would actually cost *more* lines of code, and would simply output a fixed `width` into the calculation anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

What's nice with flexbox in this case is that if your center content grows, the other columns will grow alongside!

```css
body {
  display:flex;
}

.center {
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: blue;
  max-width: 1000px;
}

.left {
  background: red;
  flex: 0 0 250px;
}

.right {
  background: green;
  flex: 0 0 350px;
}
```

```html
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="center"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
```

Comment: Ah I like this. Thank you for your solution as well :D